# Netty Connection timed out: no further information

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I am trying to detect connection problems between host & client in Java with using Netty. My problem is seems easy but I couldnt find anything because when I try my error in Google, minecraft thing comes up.

My problem is detecting wrong IPs, downed servers. For example:

I want to connect 192.168.1.1 (I made up this ip) but server is dead. Netty tries to connect it in between 5-10 secs and its huge time scale for me. How can I detect it in a shorter period of time?

## CLIENT.JAVA

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();

            clientBootstrap.group(group);
            clientBootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            clientBootstrap.remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host.getIp(), host.getPort()));

            clientBootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {

                    //TODO, TIMEOUT BILGISI ILE DOLDUR BURAYI
                    //socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(1));
                    //socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(1, 1, 2));

                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ClientHandler(host,message));
                }
            });

            ChannelFuture channelFuture = clientBootstrap.connect().sync();

            channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

I guess i have to write something in clientBootstrap.handler but I dont know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Addding this line below clientBootstrap solved for me

```
    clientBootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000);
```